# Is there a way to change query / set the epoch portion of the txid_current?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-14

The postgres documentation says that txid_current is the combination of the epoch and the current transaction id, done so that every transaction should be assigned a unique 64 bit number.

Is there any way to check what the epoch is currently?  Also - is there a way to get the server to increment the epoch?

I am using postgres 14.5.

Comment: Can you share documentation link also?

Answer (score 0):

If you know the 64-bit XID format, you can get the epoch from `pg_current_xact_id()` (Warning: consumes transaction ID if one has not been assigned to the transaction). But there is no way to force an epoch update. Epoch will advance automatically during an XID-wraparound vacuum event.

Reference: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-info.html#FUNCTIONS-PG-SNAPSHOT